# Constraining List values in jqwik with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jqwik

I'm writing jqwik tests in Kotlin. I have this parameter to one of my property tests:

```
@ForAll @Size(3) @UniqueElements emails: List<@Email @NotBlank String>
```

But when I run the test, it invariably produces

```
  emails: ["", "�", "A"]
```

which is clearly not following the constraint I thought I was giving. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you leave @NotBlank away; emails should not be blank anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried successfully:

```kotlin
@Property(tries = 100)
fun `stack overflow 77519262`(@ForAll @Size(3) @UniqueElements emails: List<@Email @NotBlank String>) {
    assert(emails.size == 3)
    assert(emails.toSet().size == 3)
    assert(emails.all { it.isNotBlank() })
    assert(emails.all { it.contains("@") })
}
```

I assume there's a misconfiguration on your side.
Here's a few things that could go wrong:

- Are you using the latest jqwik version, which is 1.8.1? Tested with Kotlin 1.8.0.
- Have you added the `jqwik-kotlin` module as a dependency? This is necessary to mitigate some of the Java-Kotlin incompatibilities.
- Have a look at the [Kotlin chapter in the user guide](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#kotlin-module) to see some of the recommended configurations for Kotlin, e.g. "-Xemit-jvm-typ-annotations", which could be the culprit in your case.